# How to delete a row instead of hiding it?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Trying to delete, rather than hide from one worksheet (where the filter button is to another where the catalogue list is. i.e. trying to create something like (best way to describe this) a shopping basket based upon the users selection and reducing the (long) list on the other worksheet after selection.

I am beginning to pull my hair out on this one and after having read and watched many, many articles on deleting rows after filtering on empty cells and today nothing has really helped as there are more issues than solutions when following codes from other, thus far.

Basically, I have a Hugh catalogue on a separate worksheet and if the user says yes, this should be shown and if not if blank (but with a value) it should be deleted. See so very basic script I have that works perfectly, but I have to delete and not hide. It appears EntireRow.delete is something beyond me, as it introduces many many issues, where hide simply worked so smoothly.

Trying many other scripts, they all really fail in simplifying the answer and 99% are actually for a single worksheet and range rather than a specific worksheet and specific columns i.e. E:E (script script below shows more) I am using a table too, so this is a little different too.

```
For a = 2 To 150
    If Worksheets("Requirements").Cells(a, 5).Value = "High" Then
        Worksheets("Requirements").Rows(a).Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

Anyone with a brilliant one or two liner to delete rather than hide, or delete all hidden if necessary

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub sjdhfs()
    For a = 150 To 2 Step -1
        If Worksheets("Requirements").Cells(a, 5).Value = "High" Then
            Worksheets("Requirements").Cells(a, 5).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

Note we run the loop from the **bottom** to the **top**.

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks and I just knew it would be much simpler than what I found in google. If you only knew what I have had to read and watch and in the end none the wiser. Many, many thanks

Comment: One further question to this, after having tried this in many examples, I noticed this is actually deleting incorrect cells and stopping on the first cell with the value I actually need deleting. E.G. 50 cells with data and excel runs through the script and deletes the 50to40 rows until it stops on row 39 where "High" was found. Anyone else experiences this and has a solution? Very strange as when all the cells are filtered correctly, so that the cells to delete are at the bottom i.e. rows 40to50 then it works.